# Modal Popup for Vimeo when clicking on Vimeo Thumbnail Link

Tags: 7, files, javascript

I have a basic link field and in this link field I just have a vimeo/youtube link. What are some of the available modules that can give the functionality of:

- Render the display of the video link with a thumbnail of the video on teaser/full display
- When clicking on the video link, a modal popup overlay will show with the video.
- The popup can also be responsive. (i guess this can be done manually via css)

Answer (score 1):

You want to have a look at the [video_embed_field](https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_field) module and the [colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) module.
They combine well to achieve what you want.

Create a contenttype with the new field provided by video_embed_field.
Then for the thumbs you could make a view and select the video_embed_field.
Go into settings of this video field and in the selectbox labeled Formatting tool, select thumbnails/w colorbox
This should give you a nice grid with thumbnails all linking to a colorbox overlay with player embedded.